# Simultaneous video recording with 2 identical cameras on Raspberry PI

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, usb-device, camera

I want to use 2 identical USB cameras to record video on Raspberry Pi 4 1GB (Raspbian 10). Both cameras have identical VID:PID (`05a3:9530`) and Serial number (SN5100), so only one of them records video at any given time.

What is strange to me, if I take photo with them:

```
fswebcam -d /dev/video0
```

or

```
fswebcam -d /dev/video2
```

it always takes photo by correct camera. So there must be some other way the OS or USB Controller is adressing them.

If both cameras are plugged in *separate* USB controllers on my PC, they both record video simultaneously. However, RPi doesn't have that option.

**What I tried:**

- Adding both cameras to OBS - only first added works
- Using them with MotionEye - same as OBS
- Using 2 different USB cameras - both work simultaneously, unfortunately this workaround is not the solution for my problem
- Playing stream from cameras with ffmpeg:

```
ffplay -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0
```

and

```
ffplay -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video2
```

First one plays OK, the second camera outputs in terminal:

```
nan: 0.000 fd= 0 aq= 0KB vq= 0KB sq= 0KB f= 0/0
```

When terminating first stream, second camera starts working instantly.

- Problem persists on any computer I tried when plugged in USB ports
  managed by *same* USB controller
- Using USB hub
- Writing in `sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4/idProduct` new PID - file not writable
- Adding custom udev rule for 1 USB port changing NAME or adding SYMLINK:

```
KERNEL=="1-1.4", NAME="device_1_4"
```

or

```
KERNEL=="1-1.4", SYMLINK+="device_1_4"
```

Note that there is no other way to distuinguish between them based on output from:

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4':
    KERNEL=="1-1.4"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb"
    DRIVER=="usb"
    ATTR{manufacturer}=="Sonix Technology Co., Ltd."
    ATTR{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTR{idVendor}=="05a3"
    ATTR{bNumInterfaces}==" 2"
    ATTR{authorized}=="1"
    ATTR{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTR{devpath}=="1.4"
    ATTR{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTR{configuration}==""
    ATTR{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTR{urbnum}=="55639"
    ATTR{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTR{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTR{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTR{idProduct}=="9530"
    ATTR{serial}=="SN5100"
    ATTR{bDeviceSubClass}=="02"
    ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="ef"
    ATTR{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTR{product}=="USB 2.0 Camera"
    ATTR{devspec}=="  (null)"
    ATTR{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTR{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTR{devnum}=="11"
    ATTR{bMaxPower}=="256mA"
    ATTR{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTR{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTR{speed}=="480"
    ATTR{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTR{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTR{busnum}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="455"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{devspec}=="  (null)"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="3431"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="2109"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0421"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.10"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0419"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.19.97-v7l+ xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:01:00.0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{devspec}=="  (null)"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="201"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:01:00.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{devspec}==""
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x3483"
    ATTRS{max_link_width}=="1"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{irq}=="54"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x3483"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1106"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1106"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x01"
    ATTRS{current_link_width}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{current_link_speed}=="5 GT/s"
    ATTRS{max_link_speed}=="5 GT/s"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:00.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="pcieport"
    ATTRS{max_link_speed}=="5 GT/s"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x0000"
    ATTRS{aer_rootport_total_err_cor}=="0"
    ATTRS{max_link_width}=="1"
    ATTRS{current_link_width}=="1"
    ATTRS{secondary_bus_number}=="1"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x14e4"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x060400"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{irq}=="53"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x2711"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x0000"
    ATTRS{subordinate_bus_number}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{devspec}==""
    ATTRS{current_link_speed}=="5 GT/s"
    ATTRS{aer_rootport_total_err_fatal}=="0"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x10"
    ATTRS{aer_rootport_total_err_nonfatal}=="0"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie':
    KERNELS=="fd500000.pcie"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="brcm-pcie"
    ATTRS{dmabounce_stats}=="m:0/0 s:0/0 f:0 s:0 b:0/0 a:0/0"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb':
    KERNELS=="scb"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

And for second camera:

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.1

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1':
    KERNEL=="1-1.1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb"
    DRIVER=="usb"
    ATTR{devspec}=="  (null)"
    ATTR{urbnum}=="146921"
    ATTR{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTR{configuration}==""
    ATTR{speed}=="480"
    ATTR{bNumInterfaces}==" 2"
    ATTR{manufacturer}=="Sonix Technology Co., Ltd."
    ATTR{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTR{devpath}=="1.1"
    ATTR{busnum}=="1"
    ATTR{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTR{bMaxPower}=="256mA"
    ATTR{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTR{serial}=="SN5100"
    ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="ef"
    ATTR{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTR{product}=="USB 2.0 Camera"
    ATTR{idProduct}=="9530"
    ATTR{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTR{idVendor}=="05a3"
    ATTR{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTR{bDeviceSubClass}=="02"
    ATTR{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTR{authorized}=="1"
    ATTR{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTR{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTR{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTR{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTR{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTR{devnum}=="9"
    ATTR{quirks}=="0x0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="3431"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="2109"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="473"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0421"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devspec}=="  (null)"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.10"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="210"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0419"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:01:00.0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.19.97-v7l+ xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{devspec}=="  (null)"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="1"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:01:00.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{current_link_speed}=="5 GT/s"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x01"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1106"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{max_link_width}=="1"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{devspec}==""
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="54"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1106"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x3483"
    ATTRS{max_link_speed}=="5 GT/s"
    ATTRS{current_link_width}=="1"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x3483"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:00.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="pcieport"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x10"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{irq}=="53"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x0000"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{max_link_width}=="1"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{subordinate_bus_number}=="1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x0000"
    ATTRS{current_link_width}=="1"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x2711"
    ATTRS{aer_rootport_total_err_cor}=="0"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x060400"
    ATTRS{max_link_speed}=="5 GT/s"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{aer_rootport_total_err_nonfatal}=="0"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{current_link_speed}=="5 GT/s"
    ATTRS{aer_rootport_total_err_fatal}=="0"
    ATTRS{secondary_bus_number}=="1"
    ATTRS{devspec}==""
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x14e4"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie':
    KERNELS=="fd500000.pcie"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="brcm-pcie"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{dmabounce_stats}=="m:0/0 s:0/0 f:0 s:0 b:0/0 a:0/0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb':
    KERNELS=="scb"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Is there a way to make them record video both at once?

Comment: How are you trying to record video from them?

Comment: I tried Motioneye, ffmpeg, OBS - same results on all of them

Comment: Great. Please add that to your question because it's useful information and it doesn't deserve to get lost in a list of comments.

Comment: Please add to the question the command line you are using to record with ffmpeg for each camera, that's too important to be left out.

Comment: Maybe the USB is saturated. With USB 2.0 you can use effective speeds of around 40 MB/s. Recording raw 720p yuyv422 images at 15 fps will hit that limit already.

Comment: Not sure about that. I now tried maxing my camera resulution to 1600x1200 30fps and trying second old usb camera at 640x480 60fps. Both work, but high resolution camera is choppy, because of bus saturation? But, _both_ work, even when choppy. Is there a way to check if USB bus is saturated?

Comment: I do not know how to check USB utilization on-wire. I looked at the data-rate of one camera with `ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -f v4l2 -pixel_format yuyv422 -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 15 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -f rawvideo - | pv > /dev/null`. `pv` shows you an approximate value. I do not know how bad the overhead of is. It is possible that one camera at 40MB/s works, but two cameras work only on 10MB/s since you lose the other 20MB/s due to switching communication on the bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Hermann in comments, streaming video from both USB cameras was made possible with:

- **FFMPEG:**

```
ffplay -f v4l2 -pixel_format mjpeg -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video0
```

and

```
ffplay -f v4l2 -pixel_format mjpeg -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video2
```

Both *-pixel_format* and *-video_size* must be combination from `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` output or `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 (or other device) --list-formats-ext`

Comment: Regarding the low frame-rate: It is possible that the cameras cannot supply high frame-rates when delivering uncompressed (YUV) frames. Compressed (MJPEG) streams might yield higher frame-rates. You can ask the driver what is possible via `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Updated the solution.